# C# textbox keydown triggered twice in metro applications

Tags: c#, xaml, microsoft-metro

I m working on C# and XAML for metro applications. I have a textbox and I want that once enter is pressed in that textbox a new textbox appears. But instead of just one textbox, I m getting two textboxes. I did debugging also n realized that its triggerd twice. Not able to figure out why it is triggerd twice.
here is some code of my application

```
private void TextBox_KeyDown_1(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Enter)
        {
          //code for producing textbox
        }

    }
```

when i m debugging, once the above block is executed, it going to LayoutAwarePage.cs
and the control is sent to ths code snippet

```
private void CoreDispatcher_AcceleratorKeyActivated(CoreDispatcher sender,
        AcceleratorKeyEventArgs args)
    {
        var virtualKey = args.VirtualKey;

       if ((args.EventType == CoreAcceleratorKeyEventType.SystemKeyDown ||
            args.EventType == CoreAcceleratorKeyEventType.KeyDown) &&
            (virtualKey == VirtualKey.Left || virtualKey == VirtualKey.Right ||
            (int)virtualKey == 166 || (int)virtualKey == 167))
        {
            var coreWindow = Window.Current.CoreWindow;
            var downState = CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down;
            bool menuKey = (coreWindow.GetKeyState(VirtualKey.Menu) & downState) == downState;
            bool controlKey = (coreWindow.GetKeyState(VirtualKey.Control) & downState) == downState;
            bool shiftKey = (coreWindow.GetKeyState(VirtualKey.Shift) & downState) == downState;
            bool noModifiers = !menuKey && !controlKey && !shiftKey;
            bool onlyAlt = menuKey && !controlKey && !shiftKey;

            if (((int)virtualKey == 166 && noModifiers) ||
                (virtualKey == VirtualKey.Left && onlyAlt))
            {
                // When the previous key or Alt+Left are pressed navigate back
                args.Handled = true;
                this.GoBack(this, new RoutedEventArgs());
            }
            else if (((int)virtualKey == 167 && noModifiers) ||
                (virtualKey == VirtualKey.Right && onlyAlt))
            {
                // When the next key or Alt+Right are pressed navigate forward
                args.Handled = true;
                this.GoForward(this, new RoutedEventArgs());
            }
        }
    }
```

once ths code block is done, the control is sent back to the function TextBox_KeyDown_1. I m nt able to understand why on the first place control is sent to layoutawarepage.cs . This code was generated when i added SplitPage in my project.

Comment: First, the  following code in LayoutAwarePage causes the event handler to execute: `Window.Current.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.AcceleratorKeyActivated +=
                        CoreDispatcher_AcceleratorKeyActivated;`

Comment: Next, I've tried using a simple `Debug.WriteLine` in the KeyDown eventhandler similar to yours - but it seems to get called only once. Can you please produce a more complete sample which causes this behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem, and found the following article on [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/734d6c7a-8da2-48c6-9b3d-fa868b4dfb1d) which says MS is aware of the bug and has filed it in their internal database.  The suggestion of handling KeyUp instead of KeyDown worked for my situation.

Comment: That article is an exact word for word copy of this question. It looks like the OP posted in multiple formus.

Comment: So it does, I hadn't read the whole question in the other thread.  The answer is still of use.